# socket.io polling returns Laravel 500 NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, laravel, socket.io

I'm trying to setup a node.js socket.io server, and it's not working. It seems like it's trying to poll to the node.js server first, but because I'm using Laravel for the majority of my app, that's picking it up and returning a `Not FoundHttpException`

#### Node.js server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var redis = require('ioredis');
var Redis = new redis();

Redis.subscribe('live-updates');

Redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);

    console.log(channel, message);
    io.emit('foo', message.data);
});

io.on('connection', function() {
    console.log('foo');
});
```

#### Client code:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://myapp.app');

socket.on('foo', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

All this does is triggers the following HTTP long polling requests in my client:

`http://myapp.app/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1447468676627-0`

which responds with:

> `Server 500 error, #29 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException in /home/vagrant/myapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:161`

Well of course it's not found. I'm expecting socket.io to attempt to create a websocket connection - not send long-polling HTTP requests to an undefined Laravel route. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am kinda new to node but you do not seem to have bound your node server to any port at the end of your script, nor are you referring to one in your client side JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need express here, as you are not displaying anything, just simple http server.
I think your issue, that the server does not listen.

Also node should listen to different port than 80, otherwise your http server will handle the request and lead to that 500 error.

Check code below.

Server side

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(3000);
```

Client side

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
```

Make sure you run node from CLI

```
node index.js
```

And replace `index.js` with your script name.

Comment: What is the variable `handler`?

Comment: I am sorry, would you elaborate more, what do you mean by variable handler?